# link_to method of ruby not working for shopify embedded app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, shopify-app

I am creating an embedded app for shopify in Ruby on Rails. And I came across a quick issue which I don't think should be a major one but I am not able to get it working so I was hoping if anyone could help me out.

Let me explain the issue.

**What I have done**

1. I have rendered a template where there are some contents and links to other controller which in return should render some other templates.
2. I have managed the routes properly.
3. The link that I have added is link this

> link_to "Automatic Install", '/greetings', :method => :get

So the problem is when I click the link it loads a blank page inside the shopify iframe not rendering the proper template file associated to **Greetings controller**.

Same thing works for normal rails app but when i do the same for the rails application which is an embedded app for shopify it is not working as expected.

This really should be due to the app being loaded on iframe as shopify loads the embedded application on iframe. Which is why it may not be working.

I couldn't find any way of make it work but i strongly believe that there should be some proper way of doing it for the embedded app.

I hope someone could help me out here or point me to a right direction.